# How to show page indicator on action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabactivity

Creating Page Tabs with page/view indicator on the action bar itself rather than below it. I tried various tutorials and examples but all show the tab/page/view indicator below the action bar only. The pages are the inflated with activities rather than fragments. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom action bar view and set it by calling getActionBar().setCustomView() or getSupportActionBar().setCustomView() (if you use support.v7 ActionBar) method. This custom view should contain custom page indicator. Then you can change page indicator state manually.
This solution is not very elegant, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks Denis, but I got the result, I created a custom header and then  used pages on it!